# XML to CSV conversion like MS Excel

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have following XML input set

```
<Bill>
   <HeaderGroup>
      <Name>Mr Consumer</Name>
      <Address>My Factory Address</Address>
   </HeaderGroup>
   <BillHistoryGroup>
      <BillHistoryRow>
         <BillMonth>JAN</BillMonth>
         <BillUnit>100</BillUnit>
      </BillHistoryRow>
      <BillHistoryRow>
         <BillMonth>FEB</BillMonth>
         <BillUnit>200</BillUnit>
      </BillHistoryRow>
      <BillHistoryRow>
         <BillMonth>MAR</BillMonth>
         <BillUnit>300</BillUnit>
      </BillHistoryRow>
   </BillHistoryGroup>
   <PaymentHistoryGroup>
      <PaymentHistoryRow>
         <PaymentMonth>SEP</PaymentMonth>
         <PaymentAmount>1000</PaymentAmount>
      </PaymentHistoryRow>
      <PaymentHistoryRow>
         <PaymentMonth>OCT</PaymentMonth>
         <PaymentAmount>1500</PaymentAmount>
      </PaymentHistoryRow>
   </PaymentHistoryGroup>
</Bill>
```

and I want to generate tabular view of the data as generated by MS Excel when I load this file with excel[image]

How can I achieve same output in C#, given that the code could dynamically understand varying number of records and columns present in the input XML data set. Any help would be higly appreciated!

Comment: So your first mission, is to learn how to deserialize xml. When you have done that, then you can move on to other component issues

Comment: First read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0, and then I recommend https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/.

Comment: *"the code could dynamically understand varying number of records and columns present in the input XML data set."* That is not possible. XML has many possible structures. There is no way to determine automatically what should be a record and what should be a column. Even the same XML could be parsed differently for different purposes. You need to establish some rules in advance - and, by necessity, those rules will only fit XML documents that have the same or similar structure.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thanks for your reply, but then how MS Excel do that

Comment: I don't know (I don't use Excel).

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            string[] headers = {"Name", "Address", "BillMonth", "BillUnit","PaymentMonth", "PaymentAmount"};

            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement bill in doc.Descendants("Bill"))
            {
                string name = (string)bill.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault();
                string address = (string)bill.Descendants("Address").FirstOrDefault();

                foreach(XElement billHistoryRow in bill.Descendants("BillHistoryRow"))
                {
                    string billMonth = (string)billHistoryRow.Descendants("BillMonth").FirstOrDefault();
                    string billUnit = (string)billHistoryRow.Descendants("BillUnit").FirstOrDefault();
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { name, address, billMonth, billUnit })); 
                }
                foreach (XElement paymentHistoryRow in bill.Descendants("PaymentHistoryRow"))
                {
                    string paymentMonth = (string)paymentHistoryRow.Descendants("PaymentMonth").FirstOrDefault();
                    string paymentAmount = (string)paymentHistoryRow.Descendants("PaymentAmount").FirstOrDefault();
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", new string[] { name, address, "", "", paymentMonth, paymentAmount }));
                }


            }


            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```